# Rounding in C++

Tags: c++, math

In C++ we have the function round():

```
round(4.1);//=4.1
round(4.5);//=5
```

But what If I want to round up a given number to the nearest integer which is greater or equal to it?

Comment: There is a method for that, `std::ceil`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ceil()` function. The `ceil()` function returns the ceiling of any number, or the nearest integer that is greater or equal to that number.

For example:

`ceil(4.5) = 5`

`ceil(3) = 3`

`ceil(-2.5) = -2`